# Can QGIS projects be opened in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, convert, file-formats, mxd

I am about to start a project with a number of people for a nonprofit organization. I am wanting to create the files in QGIS, but some of the people that I am working with are city officials and might feel more comfortable using ArcGIS for Desktop as opposed to QGIS.

If I were to create project files in QGIS could others open up them up in ArcGIS for Desktop? Or is there a way for me to export it to a file that could be opened in ArcGIS for Desktop? Or maybe there is file conversion plug-in that could be used?

Answer (score 12):

No it's not possible.

Like PolyGeo said you could write a conversion script using [ArcPy](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/02/12/what-is-arcpy/) that reads the QGIS project file (which is just XML) and load each layer.   There would be a bit of work but you might even be able to match some of the styling.  However there would be a lot of effort in this and it might not be worth it for a single project.

Comment: Is using arcpy.mapping to read the QGIS project file and add layers before saving as a *.mxd perhaps an option to do a rough translation?

Comment: True you could do that, although that's just going to give you the layers with no styling.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I asked this question 7 years ago and it turns out someone out there has found an answer to converting MXD's to Qgis. Pretty exciting to see how far we have come.

https://north-road.com/slyr/